# How to access bridged modem/router from behind a TP-Link router

Tags: networking, router, modem, bridge, bridge-router

[image: Text]
I have set up the ISP modem/router in bridged mode, which is connected to the WAN port of a TP-Link router.

I want to access the GUI of my ISP's modem/router.
I can't do this anymore. Ping to 192.168.0.1 gives a request timeout.

What exactly do I need to set?
I'm a beginner so I would like a step-by-step guide.
Thank you very much

Comment: If it's in bridge mode, it can't possibly have a 192.168.x.x address. It can only have a public IP address, and assuming a standard consumer connection with only one address, it can't have an address at all when you also have a router connected.

Comment: Use `tracert` command to any website to make sure of the IP of the second router. If it's correct then is probably blocking your request as it's not coming from the same subnet as the router. It is typical of routers only allowing web acess from their own subnet. If you really need access and your setup is a typical home one, connect your computer to the ISP router directly.